# how to prevent logout of facebook.com when i only want to logout from my website using facebook api

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

how to prevent logout of facebook.com when i only want to logout from my website using facebook api. I am working in Codeignator

thanks in advance

here is my code :

```
 if ($this->user) {
    echo(base_url());
        $data['logout_url'] = $this->facebook
            ->getLogoutUrl(array("next"=>base_url().'login/logout/'));
    } else {
        $data['login_url'] = $this->facebook
            ->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'email', 'redirect_uri'=>'http://devquest.wisesolutions.pk/login/'));
    }

    $this->load->view('login',$data);
}
function logout()
{
session_destroy();
redirect(base_url().'login');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, getLogoutUrl() returns a URL that logs the user out of Facebook.

It's also Facebook policy that the logout function of your website also logs the user out of Facebook

Comment: then what should be the best way to do this, can you please help me out by showing me some code